# JSON.NET Deserialize problem

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm strugling the whole day with the next JSON string

```
{
"0":{"link":"afbeeldingenplaatje1.jpg"},
"1":{"link":"afbeeldingenplaatje2.jpg"},
"2":{"link":"afbeeldingenplaatje3.jpg"}
}
```

How can i deserialize this? What's wrong with the next code (vb.net)

```
Public Class DataString
    Private m_link As String
    Public Property link() As String
        Get
            Return m_link
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_link = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DataToArray
    Private a_Data As Dictionary(Of Integer, DataString)
    Public Property DataTo() As Dictionary(Of Integer, DataString)
        Get
            Return a_Data
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of Integer, DataString))
            a_Data = value
        End Set
    End Property

Dim template As DataToArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataToArray)(sData)
```

it returns always an empty result.

Thanks!

Raymond

Answer (score 1):

The json data and your model does not match.

Try doing this instead:

```
Dim template As DataToArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, DataString))(sData)
```

Or change the data input to:

```
{
    DataTo: {
        "0":{"link":"afbeeldingenplaatje1.jpg"},
        "1":{"link":"afbeeldingenplaatje2.jpg"},
        "2":{"link":"afbeeldingenplaatje3.jpg"}
    }
}
```